# React router не отображает страницу полностью без перезагрузки

Tags: reactjs, router

```js
       /* Load More Post */ 
     
        $("div.blog-post").slice(0, 4).show();
          $("#load-more-post").on('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $("div.blog-post:hidden").slice(0, 1).slideDown(300);
             if ($("div.blog-post:hidden").length == 0) {
             $('#post-end-message').html('<div class="end">End</div>').fadeIn(800);
             $("#load-more-post").fadeOut(100);
              }
             });
    


       /* Load More Portfolio */ 
     
        $("div.portfolio").slice(0, 2).show();
          $("#load-more-portfolio").on('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $("div.portfolio:hidden").slice(0, 1).slideDown(300);
             if ($("div.portfolio:hidden").length == 0) {
             $('#portfolio-end-message').html('<div class="end">End</div>').fadeIn(800);
             $("#load-more-portfolio").fadeOut(100);
              }
             });
```

Столкнулся с интересной ситуевиной. `React Router` при переходе по ссылкам навигации страниц на сайте отображает только часть компонентов на странице перехода.
Т.е. если перейти, например, на страницу about она рисуется не полностью, а только часть компонентов. Нет тех компонентов, которые отличают эти страницы ,а только те, которые повторяются, такие как footer, например.

После перезагрузки страницы, она отображается корректно и полностью.
Речь идет о работе на локальном сервере.
Если перезагрузить ее на хостинге, то страницы вообще не будет, а *ошибка 404*, но это уже другой вопрос.

В средствах разработчика виден код страницы и в React tool видны недостающие компоненты, но на странице их нет.

Если кто знает как решить эту проблемку, пишите пожалуйста.

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/work" component={Work} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: какая ошибка печатет?

Comment: Вы явно делаете что-то не так. В текущем виде на ваш вопрос нельзя дать объективный ответ. Может вы в компонентах чего-то напортачили или еще где-то. Когда идет не полная отрисовка - какие ошибки в консоли, прикрепите в вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, Роман. Это уже не первое мое приложение на реакте. И раньше не возникало это проблемы. Ошибок нет в консоли, в этом и соль.

Comment: Роман, проблема действительно не в роутере. И вопрос пока закрываю, потому что не видя полной картины подсказать невозможно.

Comment: Нашел в чем проблема, но решения как пофиксить пока нет, позже напишу. Проблема в скрипте, который подгружает динамически контент. Т.е. есть кнопка, которая добавляет на страницу больше контента . И React не подружился с этим скриптом.

Comment: А как вы решили данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в скрипте JS, который подгружает динамически контент на страницу, и тем самым, контролировал отображение интерфейса, что реакту и не понравилось.